# Watin runs locally but fails on CI server

Tags: teamcity, watin

I have some watin tests using NUnit, when I run them locally, it launches IE and all tests pass, but some tests fail on TeamCity.

I have some basic tests:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    ie.GoTo(url + "/account/login");

    Assert.That(ie.ContainsText("Remember me"));
}

[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    ie.GoTo(endpoint + "/account/login");

    ie.TextField(t => t.Name == "Email").TypeText("admin");
    ie.TextField(t => t.Name == "Password").TypeText("asdfasdf");

    ie.Button(b => b.GetAttributeValue("type") == "submit").Click();

    Assert.That(ie.ContainsText("Dashboard"));
}
```

both tests pass locally, but on TeamCity the second one fails. The url of the browser (*ie.Url*) on the second test after the submit button is clicked is still "/account/login", I've even tried to navigate to another url after the login action but it redirects me to the login page.

It seems the login action is not working (again, locally everything works fine).

**Update**
The issue isn't with the buttons or the form, I've tried submitting the button manually and even navigating to a url that performs the login and redirects me to the home page. The tests are still failing on TeamCity, it's like authentication isn't working.

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance.